# Bad resolution when print panel from form

Tags: c#, printing, panel, resolution

My project is to print a panel from form

but the resolution was so terrible

I checked a lot of posts

Knowing that the main problem is DPI difference between monitor and printer

I try to set my bitmap big and print it at right size i want

but it seems i cant set them well

the resolution still bad and the size change like uncontralable

if i set my bitmap size greater then 10k

it will disappear from print preview dialog

my code here

```
    Bitmap MemoryImage;
    public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
    {

        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(9000,9000);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,9000,9000);
        pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, rect);

    }

    void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GetPrintArea(flowLayoutPanel1);
        Rectangle pagearea = new Rectangle(0,0,5000, 5000);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage,pagearea);
    }

    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
        PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("A4 300DPI", 2480, 3508);
        doc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
        dlg.Document = doc;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I want to get panel and print it on A4 with resolution like printing a word document

I spent almost a week try to solve this problem >"<

Plz save me ...

Comment: There are many references on the Web for creating an image of a form at the same DPI as the screen; but you want to scale the image up to be printed at full-page size, is that correct?

Comment: Just make sure that one pixel in the panel becomes one pixel on paper.  It will be razor-sharp.  But yes, magnifying glass required.  You can certainly print it bigger.  But then you'll need much longer arms to make it look sharp.  About 6 times longer.  The conclusion you need to draw is that it just wasn't a good idea to print a panel.

Comment: @Ghashgul hadn't you accepted my answer? i saw that.

Comment: I thought I did, maybe i clicked it twice, My bad, thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I spent almost a week try to solve this problem

You can't make it to work even if you try another week, because you are on the wrong track.

> Knowing that the main problem is DPI difference between monitor and printer

You know the problem and know that there is no solution for that you still keep trying.

**Solution:**
  If you want to render some data on report, i don't think printing of panel is the solution. you should consider printing report in the `form of a report`. Like, consider making an `RDLC/Crystal` report and put your desired data on that report. In short, **use Reports for reporting purpose**.